# ASP.NET MVC form collection on postback does not work on chrome, but works on Firefox and IE

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to Visual Studio 2015. I am trying to collect form data from the view and using form collection for the same. on post back, the form collection shows null when I use chrome, but it collects data on postback when I use FireFox or IE.
    This is my Controller:

```
        public ActionResult About(FormCollection collection, int edit = 0)
        {
            string firstName = null;
            string lastName = null;
            string email = null;
            int phone = 0;
            if (collection["FirstName"] != null && collection["FirstName"] != string.Empty)
            {
                firstName = collection["FirstName"].ToString();
            }

            if (collection["LastName"] != null && collection["LastName"] != string.Empty)
            {
                lastName = collection["LastName"].ToString();
            }
            if (collection["Email"] != null && collection["Email"] != string.Empty)
            {
                email = collection["Email"].ToString();
            }
            if (collection["Phone"] != null && collection["Phone"] != string.Empty)
            {
                phone = Convert.ToInt32(collection["Phone"]);
            }

            UserDetails UProfile = new UserDetails();
            ViewBag.Rand = "bla";
            ViewBag.LastName = lastName;

            if (collection["btnSubmit"] != null)
            {

                UProfile.FirstName = firstName;
                UProfile.LastName = lastName;
                UProfile.Email = email;
                UProfile.Phone = phone;


            }
            if (edit == 1)
            {
                ViewBag.FirstName = firstName;
                ViewBag.LastName = lastName;
                ViewBag.Email = email;
                ViewBag.Phone = phone;
            }

            ViewBag.Uprofile = (UProfile.ToString()).ToList();
            return View(UProfile);
        }
```

This is My View:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "About";
}
<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>
<br />

@Html.Label("Kindly fill the details below")
<br /><br />
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.Label("First Name: ")</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBox("FirstName", (string)ViewBag.FirstName)</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

<div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        @Html.Label("First Name: ")
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        @Html.TextBox("FirstName", (string)ViewBag.FirstName)
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        @Html.Label("Last Name: ")
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        @Html.TextBox("LastName", (string)ViewBag.LastName)
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-12"><br /><br /></div>
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        @Html.Label("Email: ")
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        @Html.TextBox("Email", (string)ViewBag.Email)
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        @Html.Label("Contact No: ")
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        @Html.TextBox("Phone", (int?)ViewBag.Phone)
    </div>
</div>
<br /><br />
<div class="col-lg-4">

</div>
<div class="col-lg-4">
    <button id="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit">@Html.ActionLink("Submit", "About", "Home", new { edit = 1 }, null)</button>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4">
    <br /><br /><br />
</div>
}
```

Why isn't it working on chrome?

Comment: I don't think you want to use that `ActionLink()` for your submit button.  Try using just a simple HTML submit button, such as `<button id="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit" type="submit">TEST Submit</button>`.

Comment: It worked. Thank you :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow -- #SOReadyToHelp